# CSS Date Picker Icons Missing

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc, datepicker

I downloaded "Date Picker" from http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ and after I moved the CSS file into my project folder, the icons are gone.

```
WEB-INF/view/templates/images  
WEB-INF/view/templates/datePickerCustomer1.css
```

In Css:

```
    .ui-widget-content 
{  
    border: 1px solid #8e846b;  
    background: #feeebd url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_feeebd_1x100.png) 50% 
    top repeat-x;  
}
```

I have already tried

```
background-image: url(images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_feeebd_1x100.png) &  
background-image: url('images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_feeebd_1x100.png') with quotes
```

None of those are not working.

**The output image**
[image: The output image]

**The correct image to get**
[image]

Comment: Try `url(/images/ui-bg_highlight-soft_100_feeebd_1x100.png)`

Comment: @Morpheus It's not working. Whether i change to url(../images/xxx.png) or url(/images/xxx.png)

Comment: Is `&emsp;&emsp;` really in your CSS file?

Comment: check your file structure and specify url with reference to your css file. if not able to do so share your file structure with us

Comment: Just inspect the element with developer tools under Styles/CSS tab and right click/open link in new tab to see where the website is trying to take the image from.

Comment: It does not matter if you have quotes in the `url('here')` or not `url(here)` they are both the same probably you don't have that image on that path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WEB-INF directory is a private area of the web application, any files under WEB-INF directory cannot be accessed directly from browser by specifying the URL like http://yousite.com/WEB-INF/images/myimage.jpeg. Web container will not serve the content of this directory.